# What would be the difference between “Noun扱いにする” and “Noun扱いする”?

Tags: grammar

> 「あたし一応税金対策のためにプロダクションを法人化してるから、正社員**扱いにできる**よ。給料は相場の倍、いや三倍出してもいい。もちろんボーナス&昇給あり。ーーなんかこう、あたしが誘って少年が断るまでがいつもの流れになっちゃってる感あるけどさ、冷静に考えてみてよ。給料よくて、通勤しやすくて、スキルも活かせる。ついでに美人の上司もいる。ウチ、かなり好条件の就職先だと思うんだけどにゃあ」

Can we just say 正社員扱いする here? Generally, what would be the difference between “Noun扱いにする” and “Noun扱いする”? Both can mean “treat... as...”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Noun + 扱いする` typically has a negative or condescending overtone. `Noun + 扱いにする` is neutral, and it's suitable in legal or business-related contexts.

For example, 子供扱いする means to treat someone as an immature/childish person, which is usually rude. 子供扱いにする means to (temporarily) regard someone as being a child for some socially valid reason.

In your case, saying 正社員扱いする in casual speech is not necessarily rude (because we all understand 正社員 is a good thing), but 正社員扱いにする is a lot safer. In formal written text, I think it's safe to say 正社員扱いする is wrong.

(Note that 正社員扱いにする in this context probably means to actually employ him as a 正社員, not "regarding" him as a 正社員.)

Comment: Is there anything about the particle に that makes the sentence neutral? Are there other similar constructs with に exhibiting the same behaviour?

Comment: @grove Aにする is a standard construction to say "to make it A", so I think what's special here is that A扱いする works as a suru-verb and tends to have a negative overtone.

Comment: I'm thinking the meaning is actually similar in some ways to the difference in English between saying, for example "treat (someone) like a child" (子供扱いする), vs "do (something) as if (someone) were a child" (子供扱いにする), which I think is kinda similar to how the difference in particles works in Japanese too..

Answer (score 1):

正社員扱いにする means treating as a full-time employee. In this situation, he/she is a part-time worker or a temporary staff. You can get more benefits. 扱いにする means treating as higher rank or lower rank.

扱いする example sentence are 子供扱いする、 treating as if she is a child. 妻を家政婦扱いする treating his wife as if she is a housekeeper.

It's used like treating as something else(other status) in a bad way.

In this sentence, 正社員扱いしてあげるよ is possible, but 正社員扱い**に**してあげる is way better. Basically 扱い is used in a bad way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127192/discussion-on-answer-by-teacandy-what-would-be-the-difference-between-noun).